# How to properly dispatch event from Stage reference

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm facing following problem from some times, and I always fail to overcome it.

I guess solution has to be provided in different way, but I would like to find out why this kind of code doesn't work.

Scenario:

Main class is Main.as in which there is a Sprite1 instance added to Main displayList.
There is also MyCustomClass instance which takes reference to Stage in constructor, to be able to dispatch an MyCustomClass.ABC event.

(in MyCustomClass)

```
stageRef.dispatchEvent(new Event(MyCustomClass.ABC));
```

then in my Main where sprite1 instance is placed on Main's displayList I want to listen for this MyCustomClass.ABC event dispatched by stage class reference from inside of MyCustomClass.

Finally if I put following code in my Main.as:

```
sprite1.addEventListener(MyCustomClass.ABC, onABC);
```

it doesn't work so I have to subscribe to this event directly by stage reference in Main class.

```
stage.addEventListener(MyCustomClass.ABC, onABC);
```

I thought that in the capture phase the event propagates from Stage to all the children, and sprite1 instance is a Main's child which is Stage's child. So, for me it should work but it doesn't.

I created an image describing objects on the displayList in this project. Please look at
link http://www.iv.pl/images/61170779800943350498.png

Thanks in advance for any explanations why it doesn't work. It doesn't work with any parameters I pass to listener (capturing) or dispatcher(bubbling).

Comment: The event propagation doesn't work that way, here, check this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html Also, what is the need to use the stage to dispatch an event? Stage has (very probably) nothing to do with your MyCustomClass's event. Seems like bad design there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

capture phase event goes from target to stage while bubbling phase goes from stage to target. When stage is the target no object in the display list can catch that dispatched event since they cannot be included in the event phases. The target (stage) goes to stage then back to target (stage) and there's nothing in between to catch the event.

Typically when using stage to dispatch an event programmers want to make use of stage global nature (design that can be argued upon) but in that type of design it also mean that only stage should listen to its own dispatching.

Comment: I still guess capture phase event goes from stage to target and opposite for bubbling, but as you mentioned in my case stage is the target so thanks for the tip - I realized that no objects would be noticed.